# How do I trigger a Cordova Webview to pop up when user clicks on a row in a native Android listview

Tags: android, android-listview, cordova-plugins, cordovawebview

I've finished the Cordova tutorial (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html). So now it's very clear how to use a Cordova webview event to trigger something in the native app. But I still don't understand how to write functionality that goes in the other direction. How can I make a native Android listview that triggers a Cordova webview to pop up when the user selects one of the rows in the native Android listview? Of course it would need to pass the data from the row that was selected as an argument to the function that calls the Cordova webview up on the screen. Here's a similar question someone answered for iOS but it still doesn't help me much for Android (and the answer doesn't give a concrete use example)  [Bind a native iOS event to a webView using a custom Cordova plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775349/bind-a-native-ios-event-to-a-webview-using-a-custom-cordova-plugin)

Comment: Just found this http://catchmayuri.blogspot.in/2011/05/getting-access-of-android-java-code-to.html. Apparently DroidGap is an Android class that you can use to communicate with Cordova

Comment: This tutorial answers my question very nicely: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en